# Facebook posting items from another web sites

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am new to Facebook API development and I have general questions about how developers use Facebook.
Is it possible to post to a wall text, image, videos from another site using an FB API? Which API could use for this? Will they look like if they were posted inside facebook or they have a different appearance?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. First create a app on facebook using http://developers.facebook.com/ .

For more information go to below link

```
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/
```